# Not able to uninstall bundler 1.2.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails version 3.0.0. and i have bundler version 1.2.3. but while running bundle install its showing "This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler".. I am trying to uninstall this 1.2.3 but its showing  "INFO:  gem "bundler" is not installed". Please help me to solve this problem..

Comment: Please provide information about how you set up Ruby on your machine.

Comment: means?? i am not getting your question.

Comment: How did you install Ruby on your machine? Did you use RVM? Did you use rbenv?

Comment: yes. i used rvm to install..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
       type  $ gem list | grep bundler  # it will list all the bundler version

       then $ rvmsudo gem uninstall bundler # it will list all the version to uninstall. we have to choose all versions.

       thats it. Then we can install our required version as follows.


        rvmsudo gem install bundler -v=1.0.21
```

Comment: When I run `gem list` I get a different version than when I run `bundler -v`.